# Losing solutions when calculating an eigenvector with an unknown

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    a & 2a+5 & a+1 \\
    0 & -4 & 0 \\
    0 & 3 & -1 \\
    \end{pmatrix} 
$$
For the matrix above, where a is a positive constant,
I am comfortable with finding the eigenvalues using the characteristic equation, the first of which is $\lambda = a$. However, after this point, I start to get quite confused. Using the equation $(M-\lambda I)e = 0,  $ to find the eigenvector, e, I get

$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    a-a & 2a+5 & a+1 \\
    0 & -4-a & 0 \\
    0 & 3 & -1-a \\
    \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
    x \\
    y \\
    z  \\
    \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
    0 \\
    0   \\
    0  \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$

The problem I'm finding is now the whole first column is equal to 0, so I don't know how I can find the eigenvector as x is not present in any of the resultant equations. The answer, is $\begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\
    0   \\
    0  \\
    \end{pmatrix}$

I'm learning this as part of a high school course, and I am not very knowledgeable about eigen anything, so if anyone can help me understand I'll be really thankful.

Answer (score 1):

The equality$$\begin{bmatrix}a-a & 2a+5 & a+1 \\0 & -4-a & 0 \\0 & 3 & -1-a  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x \\y \\z\\\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0 \\0\\0  \\\end{bmatrix}$$is the system$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}(2a+5)y+(a+1)z=0\\(-4-a)y=0\\3y+(-1-a)z=0.\end{array}\right.\tag1$$And it is precisely because there is no $x$ here that every triplet $(x,0,0)$ is a solution of the system: as long as $y=0$ and $z=0$, $x$ can be *anything* and you will still get $(0,0,0)$. And it's not hard to see that, unless $a\in\{-4,-1\}$, there are no other solutions. If $a=-4$, then $(1)$ is just$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}-3y-3z=0\\3y+3z=0,\end{array}\right.$$and therefore the vectors of that form $(0,a,-a)$, with $a\ne0$, are also eigenvectors. With $a=-1$ the terms in $z$ disappear from (1) also, giving eigenvectors of the form $(0,0,a), a\not=0$ .

Comment: Thanks, that makes it clear to me. Another pretty unrelated question is do you think it's better to use the factored form like above or just Me = $\lambda$e?

Comment: That's a matter of tast. I use $(M-\lambda\operatorname{Id})e=0$.

Comment: If $a=-4$ we get $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,-1)$ as eigenvectors.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Right. I will edit my answer. Thank you.